# Avoid time of loading image in Gridview (Android)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-gridview

in my application I import the images from mobile database and display this into my application's gridview.I wrote the following code in my activitiy's onCreate() for same..

```
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,};

    Cursor mImageCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null ); 

    if (mImageCursor != null)
    {

        mImageCursor.moveToFirst();

        for (int i = 0; i < mImageCursor.getCount(); i++)
        {
            Images im=new Images();
            eachImageView=new ImageView(this);
            int imageId = mImageCursor.getInt((mImageCursor.getColumnIndex( MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)));
            selectedImageUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageId);

            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

            Bitmap bm = getScaledImage(selectedImageUri, 2, cr);
            im.setBitmap(bm);
            eachImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
            im.setImageView(eachImageView);

            arrayOfImages.add(im);

            mImageCursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
```

But the problem is that it takes too much time when the number of images are more.I heard about the async task to reduce this time but i am confused how to implement it in my code.
please provide me solution.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask are used if you want to perform operation without freezing the UI thread.
In your case you could use one. However it seems that you are loading the images when your activity is started so you can use a Loader.

Very good exemple are available in the documentation and DemoApi.

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#AsyncTask) and [Loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)